# Apache doesn't start after update

Tags: apache, server, centos, centos7

I'm running few things on CentOS 7. Everything was working fine until full update with `yum update`. Can't launch Apache since.

I tried everything including removing and reinstalling httpd.

The error I'm getting is this:

```
**systemctl status httpd.service**
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-07-09 20:50:18 CEST; 34min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 5785 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5785 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 09 20:50:18 vps.xyz.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 09 20:50:18 vps.xyz.com httpd[5785]: [Thu Jul 09 20:50:18.618214 2020] [so:warn] [pid 5785] AH01574: module systemd_module is already ...skipping
Jul 09 20:50:18 vps.xyz.com httpd[5785]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Jul 09 20:50:18 vps.xyz.com httpd[5785]: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbfServerRoot', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included ...guration
Jul 09 20:50:18 vps.xyz.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 09 20:50:18 vps.xyz.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jul 09 20:50:18 vps.xyz.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jul 09 20:50:18 vps.xyz.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

It doesn't matter how I edit httpd.conf, it always shows me the same \xef\xbb\xbf error.

Comment: Share httpd.conf file content in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an encoding issue. Could you please encoding type of httpd.conf file. It should be UTF-8 Unicode text

```
file httpd.conf
```

i.e

```
[test@test bin]# file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

On Notepad++ you can use the Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8 without BOM option to remove it

Comment: I did that. I'm getting different error now:

 `httpd[2005]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443`      
`Jul 10 12:48:40 vps.xyz.com httpd[2005]: no listening sockets available, shutting down`      
`Jul 10 12:48:40 vps.xyz.com httpd[2005]: AH00015: Unable to open logs`

Comment: Check if nay process running on port 443 using `netstat -tunlp | grep :443`. Also make sure that you are using single Listen entry for 443 port.

Comment: `netstat -tunlp | grep :443` doesn't return anything

Comment: Could you please check if you are using multiple Listen entry for 443 port. Keep single Listen entry for 443 port and test.

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Check `Listen 443` this line in conf,conf.d folder

Comment: I found this line in conf/httpd.conf and conf.d/ssl.conf

Comment: Comment one listen entry and start apache service.